# Every time i run my code i keep getting the same error

Tags: java

Can anyone help me with my java code for my assignment every time I run my program, I keep getting this error and I dont know what to do:

```
public class Earth {
private static double[][] arrayOfEarth;
public static void readDataArray(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    int rows = 2500000;
    int columns = 3;

    arrayOfEarth = new double[rows][columns];
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] line = input.nextLine().trim().split("/t ");
        for (int a = 0; a < arrayOfEarth.length; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < line.length; b++) {
                arrayOfEarth[a][b] = Double.parseDouble(line[b]);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayOfEarth));
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0    90  -4228"
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:543)
at com.company.assignment.Earth.readDataArray(Earth.java:22)
at com.company.assignment.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Comment: The error message tells you that it tries to parse "0    90  -4228" as a number, wich fails for obvious reasons. Your splitting of the string does not seem to work as you intend it to be

Comment: `"/t "` should probably be `"\\t "` or even better `"\\s+"`

Answer (score -1):

There is a number of possible problem sources. First of all, there should be `\t` not `/t`, but it's better to use simple " " - this works for sure. Also, there can be a kind of a problem in `parseDouble()` and auto-casting if you use an old Java version - this way you have to update it.

Comment: One wonders what you think "/t " would do if it were "working."